# Simulate that PC is connected to router via WiFi, but not via Ethernet

Tags: wireless-networking, ethernet, simulation

I play Hearthstone and established home Brawl. But to receive bonus they require 3 devices connected via WiFi. I have WiFi router and my PC connected to it with Ethernet cable. My 2 phones connected via WiFi, but PC can't see it inside game. But it's same router.

Is there way to simulate that PC is connected to router via WiFi, but still using Ethernet?

Comment: Most routers transparently bridge traffic between Wi-Fi and the LAN ports. I'm surprised this isn't working for you. Can you usually discover services between Wi-Fi and LAN? Can you look at your router settings to see if it has any settings about isolating LAN from Wi-Fi, or isolating Wi-Fi clients from each other? Is there any chance your Wi-Fi clients are on a "guest network" instead of the main network?

Comment: No, guest network and isolation are disabled. My PC see phone accounts in network and able to play with them. But to receive bonuses game require connection to WiFi spot.